# mapbox ios mapView.setCenter Not working for me (swiftui)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have two views (BoxView and MapboxMap).
I've tried:

1. Setting mapView.centerCoordinates when a button is selected from BoxView.
2. Calling the view, MapboxMap(coords: {insert CLLocationCoordinate2D data} ) when a button is selected from BoxView.
3. Calling mapView.setCenter() when a button is selected from BoxView.
4. Passing variables to MapboxMap View, then including everything previously mentioned in the updateAnnotations() function. (Which outputs the correct coordinate data, but doesn't change the view of the map)

I'm completely stuck. I've even used static data on a single button to rule out incorrectly passing variables to functions and/or views, but nothing will get that map view to update or change.

Can someone explain to me how this is supposed to be accomplished?!?!